The way to debug an expo app that is installed through the play store but crashes
Is "adb logcat" the best way to debug an installed Android app that crashes after installation? I have an expo app that runs normally during development (expo go). However after releasing an internal test on the play console and installing the app, it crashes after the splash screen. Is adb logcat command the way to go in this situation? Or there's a better alternative? I have an Android device. I desire to avoid using Android Studio. I don't like the emulators. I use Linux and if I would use Android Studio I'd rather change my environment to Windows. So is "adb locat" enough?

adb locat gave me "com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not fo" I searched for a solution and the solution was to install an npm library related to screens. So I think adb locat is the way to debug installed apps.

A second time my app crashed and what helped was the adb locat command. For those that don't know about it. I enable developer mode in my android device, plug the usb on the pc and run "adb locat" on the expo project so I get "Java" errors on visual code when I run my installed app on my device.
